# Create STATIC and SHARED libraries with Clang

Tags: c++, linker, clang, static-libraries, dynamic-library

What is the minimal `commmand line` way to create an static and a dynamic library with `Clang` under `Linux` and `Windows`, and then, link it against an executable?

Suppose the project contains a `main.cpp` file with the `main` function, an `lib_header.h` file under `/include/project_name` and a `lib_source.c or lib_source.cpp` under `/src`

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For both static and dynamic libraries, you first compile the source files individually:

```
clang -c -o lib_source.o lib_source.c -fPIC
```

For the static library on Linux, archive all .o files together:

```
ar r library.a lib_source.o
```

For the shared library, link with the `-shared` flag:

```
clang -shared -o library.so lib_source.o
```

Comment: You need to mention `-fPIC` for shlibs.

Comment: Quite simple and perfect explanation. Thanks.

Comment: The ` -fPIC ` (Position-Independent Code) flag is not required when generating a static library